# MySQL QUERY to get row where column ellipse number >= 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Posts 
-------------
5
4
6
7
3
```

I want to get the rows where Posts - 4 >= 1
that mean i wanna get

```
QUERY Result : 
5
6
7
```

Something like that : SELECT content FROM mytable `WHERE (Posts - 4) >= 1` LIMIT 10
Thanks

Comment: And what is wrong with that `where` clause in the question?

Comment: And have you actually tried?

Comment: So you want to find every row where Posts >= 5?

Comment: @SamHuckaby That number **4** can be changed to other numbers its not constant it can be 5 6 or more

Comment: So try it.... you'd get your answer faster than posting a question here

Comment: So `Posts >= 1 + number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So then you could use:

```
SELECT content FROM mytable WHERE Posts >= (1 + "yournumber") LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This can solve if the numbers was 4 and if it was 5 or 6 or more how can i do that i cant use evry time new number :(

Comment: @AlphaRootMks Just make your query by 1 + whatever your number is and use the above query.

Comment: Another option would be to think for oneself, or pay @SamHuckaby a consulting fee.

Comment: Thanks that fix th problem ! have a nice day (y)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this (if I'm reading you want to take the value in your column and subtract some number from it, then narrow the results which are 1 or greater).

`SELECT content FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn-4 >= 1`

Comment: That's a bad idea, performance wise. Of course that's not really an issue if you never have more than 5 records per table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this with php, create a variable to hold your number, create a query parameter from it, and send the paramter to your query.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
SELECT content FROM mytable WHERE Post >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) LIMIT 10
```